# Why is the DATA in SMTP not null terminated?

Tags: email, smtp, protocols

I was reading the original RPC about the SMTP Protocol and came across this section:

> SMTP indicates the end of the
> mail data by sending a line containing only a period.

Why did Postel decide to use the period as the terminator? Would it not be easier to use the already existing null terminator?

I see, that he would not want the users content to interfere with the protocol, but I would naively assume, that a user is more likely to use a period in one line than a null terminator?
Added to that, would the implementation of the mail client not just cut of the text if the user came to use the null terminator his mail contents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**IMHO:** SMTP has be designed long time ago to be *human readable/writable*.
It is pretty simple to test (send simple SMTP messages) typing them by hand via `telnet` program.
"Human readable" makes null terminator a suboptimal choice.

EMSMTP design is a fossil of pre-spam era.  It is bad (by current standards) but it is so widely implemented and sufficiently good (after fixes) to make any quick revolution "not sufficiently urgent".

Extra info: Seen [RFC 3030](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3030) for `BDAT` alternative to `DATA` command.

Comment: Additionally, I don't think you could reliably expect to be able to conveniently put arbitrary byte values in packets on some of the platforms which were popular at the time. My understanding is that the necessity to restrict everything to ASCII was not just convenience.

Comment: @tripleee I am afraid you are right.  :Let's hope it is an ancient history.

Comment: If the SMTP protocol was invented right now, would there be any drawbacks for the null terminator?

Comment: Yes, you would still have to escape bytes which consist only of zeros. Instead of a text-based protocol with escape sequences, a modern message protocol should be binary with a length prefix, in my opinion.